# Help solving a cubic polynomial function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics

I’m tutoring a high school pre-calc student who has to find the roots of a 3rd degree polynomial equation for homework, and I’m struggling to figure out what they are without using an online calculator or the cubic formula. Her teacher seems to suggest that there is another way to do it. Any thoughts?

$$525=(2t+3)(2t+5)(2t+7)$$

EDIT: New Age Special Effects, Inc., prepares computer software based on specifications by film directors.  To simulate an approaching vehicle, they begin with a computer image of a 5cm by 7cm by 3cm box. The program increases each dimension at a rate of 2cm/sec.  How long does it take for the volume V of the box to be at least 5 times its original size?

Comment: Let $u = 2t + 5$ because of the symmetry?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the given problem?  It does not appear to have pleasant roots.  You can rewrite it as $525=x(x+2)(x-2)$ if you like, but it does not really help.  [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+525%3D%282t%2B3%29%282t%2B5%29%282t%2B7%29) are the closed form solutions.

Comment: @abiessu That might work if $t$ was an integer.  Unfortunately it isn't.

Comment: @lulu yes this does not help.  Because I guess there are no rational roots.

Comment: Agreed, likely typo somewhere.  $105 = (2t+3)(2t+5)(2t+7)$ is much cleaner.  You'd learn that $t=0$ is a solution and be able to factor and solve the quadratic like normal after.

Comment: @JMoravitz you must mean $105=(2t+3)(2t+5)(2t+7)$

Comment: @lonestudent  That's right.  At first glance, I assumed that the problem must have an obvious rational root, which would then reduce it to a simple quadratic.  But there are no rational roots.

Comment: Thanks for all your input! I've added the word problem itself to the question to provide some context. Perhaps I made an error in modeling the equation? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You definitely created the correct equation for the word problem you have been given.

Comment: You have asked this question twice. Please delete the other instance. If the problem asked for triple the volume the answer would be $t=1$. This problem has an ugly answer between $1$ and $2$. I would find it by guess and check with an ordinary calculator.

Comment: Please don't post the same question repeatedly.  Keep this one up, delete the copy.  In any case:  you have set up the correct equation, but given the context I suspect that all that is wanted is a simple numerical approximation.  Trial and error quickly gets you a few digits of the real valued answer.

Comment: Note that "three times the size" gives you $315 =$ your polynomial and this has an easy root.